# How to build a form that on submit sends back a file to the end user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm building a form that on submit needs to send the user a file to download.

My form:

```
<form method="GET" action="/data_export" class="form-horizontal">
    <input id="user_current_password" type="password" class="input" name="user[current_password]">
    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Download</button>
</form>
```

Controller:

```
  def index
        send_data Group.to_csv(@groups),
                  :type => 'text/csv; charset=utf-8; header=present', 
                  :disposition => "attachment; filename=groups.csv"
  end
```

The problem is when submitting the form, the page redirects to a page with the text. It does not trigger a download of a file. How can I get the form submit to cause a file download?

Comment: Weird. What browser are you using? This works for me..

Comment: Chrome on a mac w Rails 3.2.11

Comment: Firefox and Safari both work. Chrome does not.

Comment: This is properly a problem with the settings in your browser (chrome).

Comment: I have used charset=iso-8859-1; in recent application and it was working. Can you try that ?